# Graphing a multi variable function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, graphing

I have never used MATLAB before, so I am very lost. For my calculus class, we were tasked with finding a certain function and then using MATLAB to graph it. Finding the function was no problem. However, trying to graph it has me pulling my hair out. The function is z(x,y)= xy(x+y)(2x+y)(3x+y)(x-2y)(x-3y)(x-4y). Any help or advice is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: What is the range for variables x and y? You may take a look at [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html?searchHighlight=surf&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) function.

Comment: I am trying the surf function, but am getting an error message with my function. It says, "Error: File: M247.m Line: 2 Column: 16
Invalid expression. Check for missing
multiplication operator, missing or unbalanced
delimiters, or other syntax error. To construct
matrices, use brackets instead of parentheses."

Comment: post your code (?!)

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [anonymous function](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) handle.

```
% define function
% .* denotes element wise multiplication
f = @(x,y) x.*y.*(x+y).*(2*x+y).*(3*x+y).*(x-2*y).*(x-3*y).*(x-4*y);

% define range and resolution for x and y
x = -20:0.5:20;
y = -20:0.5:20;

% create meshgrid for 3d plotting
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

% calculate z values (for meshgrid)
z = f(X, Y);

% plot the function
figure()
surf(x,y,z)
```

To explain further, since you want to calculate the z value for x and y pairs, you should use a element wise multiplication [`.*`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html).

Then you have to create a [`meshgrid`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) for the x and y values, to have all the possible x and y pairs in the two new matrices `X` and `Y`. Providing these to your function will calculate the corresponding `z` value for all these pairs. You can use these for plotting, e.g. surf.

[image]